# немогу canvas отрисовать в canvas -е

Tags: javascript, html5

Хочу нарисовать два независимых canvas-a но друг в друге.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html style="color:white;">
   <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title> evilGame </title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black"> 
            <canvas id="smallCanvas" width="800" height="550" style="background: red">
            </canvas>
            </canvas>

    </body>
```

Проблема в том что больший отрисовывается а меньший нет (хотя в коде он виден).

Comment: Зря хочешь... Так нельзя.

Comment: @Qwertiy  а как можно ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Спецификация](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-canvas-element) явно указывает, что это невозможно:

> The contents of the canvas element, if any, are the element's ***fallback content***.

А `fallback content` - это контент который будет виден, если внешний элемент не может быть отображен ([источник](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#fallback-content)):

> ***fallback content***: content that is to be used when the external resource cannot be used (e.g. because it is of an unsupported format).

---

Чтоб добиться чего-то подобного Вашей задаче, можно использовать 2 абсолютно позиционированных канваса:

```html
<canvas width="500" height="300" style="background: black;"> 
</canvas>

<canvas width="400" height="200" style="background: red; position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Но вообще, canvas'ы нужны, чтобы на них _рисовать_, а не раскладывать один поверх другого...

Comment: @Qwertiy Полностью согласен. Не знаю, что мешает автору просто отрисовать все нужное на одном канвасе, но если дано условие, что их нужно именно 2, то раскладывание - единственный вариант...

Comment: @Zoltan Toth Спасибо. А я как то и не подумал об абсолютном позиционировании